# "Starter" moves on evolved Pokémon

Tags: pokemon-series

[Lots](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Raichu_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) [of](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/026.shtml) [sites](http://veekun.com/dex/pokemon/raichu) state that certain Pokémon have some starter/level 1 moves that can be learned.

For example, for Raichu, Thunder Shock, Tail Whip, Quick Attack and Thunderbolt are listed; Bulbapedia states that:

> will be known by a Raichu obtained at level 1 in Generation VI

Is this actually true? Since a Raichu can't hatch from an egg or be caught in the wild, is he actually able to learn these moves without inheriting it from its pre-evolution? Or is this just a quirk from these databases?

Comment: even if you caught a level one raichu in the wild wouldn't it not be able to "learn" anything until you level it up. Now in you mean using a tm/hm then yes you can do that any time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple situations for moves that are obtained "at level 1" (Bulbapedia lists them as learned at "Start"):

For a Pokemon's first evolution, either by being caught (at levels low enough to not have learned many moves from level up) or hatched, their move list will be populated by these level-1 moves. Hatched pokemon may have a number of these moves replaced by those passed down by their parents, like egg moves.

For the other uses, often on more evolved Pokemon, I like to point to [Aegislash](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Aegislash_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29#By_leveling_up). It learns no moves by leveling, yet it's signature move that allows it to transform back to to the defensive shield forme, [King's Shield](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/King's_Shield_%28move%29), is a 'level 1' move, and not learned by it's prior evolutions. In cases like this, the intended way to obtain these moves on the Pokemon is through the [Move Reminder](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Move_Reminder).

Answer (score 1):

The starter moves are the moves that the pokemon will have if at level one, even if they are not obtainable at level 1. In this case if you encounter a level 1 Raichu in the wild (not possible playing a legit game), it will have these moves. These moves can be accessed via the move reminder.